# How do I delete a vocabulary programmatically?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 8

In Drupal 7 there was `taxonomy_vocabulary_delete($vid)`, but this doesn't seem to be there in Drupal 8.

What's the equivalent code for Drupal 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe I have figured this out. You have to load the vocabulary using the `Vocabulary` entity class, then call the delete method on it. So something like this:

`Vocabulary::load($vid)->delete();`

Comment: But how do you delete by vocabulary name?

Comment: In Drupal 8, the vocabulary ID is the machine name of the vocabulary. The shown code is doing already that.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $tids = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
    ->condition('vid', 'tags')
    ->execute();

  $controller = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term');
  $entities = $controller->loadMultiple($tids);
  $controller->delete($entities);
```

Or

```
     $vid = 'tags';
      $tids = Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
          ->condition('vid', $vid)
          ->execute();
      entity_delete_multiple('taxonomy_term', $tids);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it

```
$vocabularies = [
'test',
'second_test'
];
foreach ($vocabularies as $vocabulary) {
    $vocab = Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Vocabulary::load($vocabulary);
    if ($vocab) {
        $vocab->delete();
    }
}
```